# Where the logs from Global.java go?

Tags: logging, playframework-2.0, onstart

I'm testing the last stable version of play framework.
I created the     `Global.java` class and overridden the method     `onStart` where I put the      `Logger.info("test...");`

And I can't see the this log anywhere (no server console, no application.log file).

How can I configure the logger for Global?

Comment: Please show some code.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
After adding the logger.xml file in conf folder with next content

```
<configuration>

<conversionRule conversionWord="coloredLevel" converterClass="play.api.Logger$ColoredLevel" />

<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>${application.home}/logs/application.log</file>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%date - [%level] - from %logger in %thread %n%message%n%xException%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%coloredLevel %logger{15} - %message%n%xException{5}</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<logger name="play" level="INFO" />
<logger name="application" level="INFO" />

<root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</root>
</configuration>
```

I see the logs in server console.